# ruby: Can't create new file

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a command line program that asks the user a set of questions and stores them in a file. The only problem is, I need it to create a new file and it won't.

Here is what I have tried:
`File.open("path/to/file", "w")`
and `File.open("path/to/file", "w+")`

Both times I get this error
`in 'initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - path/to/file (Errno::ENOENT)`

Here is my current code:
`File.open("path/to/file", "w") { |f| f.write(array.join("\n")) }`

Comment: Does the directory `path/to` exist? Usually it's safer to specify the full path to avoid ambiguity. You can use [`File.expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path) to resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

When someone writes `path/to/file` in a blog post or documentation, they don't intend for you to *literally* write `path/to/file` in your code.  The point is that you need to edit that string to actually have the real path to your file, either as a relative path or an absolute path.

You said you are getting this error from the Ruby interpreter:

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - path/to/file (Errno::ENOENT)

This means that in the current working directory, there is no directory named "path", or if there is a directory named "path", then it doesn't have a child directory named "to".

You could solve the immediate problem by running `mkdir -p path/to`, but that would be weird.  It is better to just write an appropriate path in your code, pointing to a directory that already exists.  Try changing the path to simply be `output.txt` (without any slashes) and see how that works.

Comment: I tried getting rid of the slashes and print to output.txt and it gave me a new error: Invalid Argument @ rb_sysopen - output.txt (Errno::EINVAL)

Comment: Well, that's odd.  Maybe you gave a bad mode string?  How about you post your entire code, and include a shell session that shows exactly what directory you are in when you run it, how you run it, and the full output?  And please tell us exactly what type of environment you are running Ruby in.  This information should be added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using an absolute path, and if so, make sure the directory you want to store the file in is missing.  Try creating it first:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mkdir_p '/path/to'
File.open('/path/to/file', 'w') { ... }
```